# MYSQL - Displaying 2 types of data based on 2 different columns

Tags: mysql

> 1. List the Book Code and Book Title of each book with the Type SFI and is in paperback.

So I'm trying to run a query for one of the labs at university and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Here's what I have so far

```
SELECT BOOK_CODE, TITLE
FROM BOOK
WHERE (PAPERBACK = 'Y', TYPE = 'SFI')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` condition is not correct

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 ...;
```

You can find some examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) or in your professors slides... ;)